# How do you display all values when using pivot tables in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

```
df_agg = pd.pivot_table(df, values= 'total_revenue', index= 'order_year',aggfunc= 'sum')
```

**When I run the above code, this is what I get. I would love to get the entire figures for the total revenue column.**

| order_year | total_revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 4.95994e+08 |
| 2011 | 5.23411e+08 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add  pandas set_option to change the way you view the numbers.

**Code**

```
df_agg = pd.pivot_table(df, values= 'total_revenue', index= 'order_year',aggfunc= 'sum')
#Used 2 as I think you have financial/currency data
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x) 
df_agg
```

**Output**

[image]